# `ng-attr-id` and `id` not working with uibModal opened from angular CTRL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am attempting to open a modal from an angular (1.6.X) `ctrl`. I have an OK workaround using `$uibModal` resolve, but I am curious if the following is a timing issue or something I've set up poorly.

```
// angular ctrl
stepsCtrl.openModal = function(step) {
  var templateUrl = "step-" + step.id + "-modal.html";

  var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    ... modal instance config ...
    templateUrl: templateUrl
  })
}

// step index HTML
<li class="list-group-item"
    ng-repeat="step in stepsCtrl.mainSteps"
    ng-click="stepsCtrl.openModal(step)">
  <script type="text/ng-template"
          // ALSO TRIED THIS USING id="step-{{ step.id }}-modal.html" 
          ng-attr-id="{{ 'step-' + step.id + '-modal.html" }}">
    ... some stuff for modal ...
  </script>
```

Taking a look at the DOM I see a script with the correct ID on each `li` 
[image]

however I get this error during the `ng-click` event:

[image]

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Try giving the relative path   var templateUrl = "/step-" + step.id + "-modal.html";

Comment: A good idea but ultimately still no dice. Same error with the GET - `GET http://localhost:8001/step-16-modal.html 404 (Not Found)` but a new template error `Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: /step-16-modal.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)`

Comment: Where is your step modal template located? It is not taking the correct path. Maybe try giving it from the root of the folder?

Comment: The template is created within the `li` and `ng-repeat` so I have access to the step each modal is resolving. Serving it from root may work, but I'm not certain it'd gain me much as I think it'd be more difficult and less maintainable compared to my workaround. It's definitely the path coming in wrong - it works when I serve a static ID like `stepModal.html` but not with a dynamic ID. Appreciate the interest and thoughts